# Rails layout for main page width 100% width and others (input forms) with narrow width

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, layout, sass

I'm building a page where the main page has a left and right bars with fixed width, but the main contents is auto-sized with the width of the browser.

The problem I have is that when I want to view scaffolds I want the page to be just 700px or something like that and not the main layout.  So the question is, how can I setup in Rails to have two master layouts?

As I'm talking about two layouts I think it would be best for forms to float on top of the other page (with some JS or something like that).

Regards,
Johann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to specify different layouts, you can take a look here: [Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts).

Basically you can create a new layout `example.html.erb` inside `app/views/layouts/` and use it your controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'example'
end
```

All views rendered by this controller will use the `example.html.erb` layout.

Hoep this helps.